# TypeGraphQL - Not able to match all the interfaces of a union

Tags: graphql, typegraphql

#### Summary

The goal is to declare the return type of a mutation using a union in order to express multiple states: Success and user errors

Being able to select concrete types according to the use cases:

```
mutation($data: CreateUserInput!) {
  createUser(data: $data){
    ... on CreateUserSuccess {
      user {
        id
      }
    }
   ... on EmailTakenError {
    emailWasTaken
  }
  ... on UserError {
    code
    message
  }
  }
}
```

Implementation using TypeGraphQ:

```
@ObjectType()
class CreateUserSuccess {
  @Field(() => User)
    user: User
}
@ObjectType()
class EmailTakenError {
  @Field()
    emailWasTaken: boolean
}

const mapMutationValueKeyToObjectType = {
  user: CreateUserSuccess,
  code: UserError,
  emailWasTaken: EmailTakenError
}
const CreateUserPayload = createUnionType({
  name: 'CreateUserPayload',
  types: () => [CreateUserSuccess, EmailTakenError, UserError] as const,
  resolveType: mutationValue => {
    const mapperKeys = Object.keys(mapMutationValueKeyToObjectType)
    const mutationValueKey = mapperKeys.find((key) => key in mutationValue)

    return mapMutationValueKeyToObjectType[mutationValueKey]
  }
})

@InputType()
class CreateUserInput implements Partial<User> {
  @Field()
    name: string

  @Field()
    email: string
}

@Resolver(User)
export class UserResolver {
  @Mutation(() => CreateUserPayload)
  createUser (@Arg('data', {
    description: 'Represents the input data needed to create a new user'
  }) createUserInput: CreateUserInput) {
    const { name, email } = createUserInput

    return createUser({ name, email })
  }
}
```

Data layer

```
export const createUser = async ({
  name, email
}: { name: string; email: string; }) => {
  const existingUser = await dbClient.user.findUnique({
    where: {
      email
    }
  })

  if (existingUser) {
    return {
      code: ErrorCode.DUPLICATE_ENTRY,
      message: "There's an existing user with the provided email.",
      emailWasTaken: true
    }
  }

  return dbClient.user.create({
    data: {
      name,
      email
    }
  })
}
```

#### Issue

The response doesn't resolve all of the selected fields according to their unions, even by returning fields that are related to different types

```
 if (existingUser) {
    return {
      code: ErrorCode.DUPLICATE_ENTRY,
      message: "There's an existing user with the provided email.",
      emailWasTaken: true
    }
  }
```

[image]

My doubt is this case is, why `emailWasTaken` is not being returned within the response if the `EmailTakenError` type is being selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an interpretation mistake on my part

The reasoning is that resolvers with a union type as the return definition should indeed just return one of those, in the case above, `UserError` and `EmailTakenError` wouldn't be returned on the same response

[More info on this GitHub discussion](https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/discussions/1179#discussioncomment-2034034)